# Azure Form Recognizer duplicating text extracted from PDF

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

While extracting values using Azure Form Recognizer, many values are shown duplicated.

I have trained a custom model labelling the appropriate key values. I find that the OCR duplicates the boxes, so that when I am labelling using the sample labeling tool I often get one box inside the other.I need to pick one and deselect the other, to avoid showing the value duplicated.

When I run the model to predict a new PDF for many keys I also get the values duplicated.

Furthermore, upon inspection of the Result JSON I can see that many Lines have the Bounded Boxes nested, or overlapping. That is, typically you would have a Line that has a bounded box and text associated that in turn have "Words" that have a bounded box inside the Bounded Box of the Line.

Just to clarify, in the JSON I am seeing Lines, that have overlapping or nested Bounded Boxes and therefore text.

Any clues as to why this can be?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could show a sample of the pdf file you used.  When you use the sample pdf documents,  such problem didn't happen, right? 
sample data file could be found here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/blob/master/curl/form-recognizer/sample_data.zip

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I did not try with the sample data. I think it does not happen with PDF that have the text as text embedded as  opposed to image. Glad to supply a sample ( "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vyr89ROppjZHMeZDE6ppRn61bhGFBbfh/view ). I guess just trying to label one example will show the first part. Let me know if there is anyway I can help

Comment: Hi, is  there any solution to this I am facing same problem of duplicate values.

Comment: hi,  I have left Microsoft, so I couldn't update you with the latest solution.  I think the Azure Form team is working on improvements in this area,  please give their latest version a try.